# Getting Sharepoint-hosted app current user from within ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net

i have an ASP.NET Web API which i'm using in my SharePoint-hosted app to do CRUD operations via REST. I want to get the current user's credentials (O365 account) from within my web api controllers? Is it possible? Any suggestions or referenced would be much appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using the below code in my controller:

```
Uri targetWeb = new Uri(HttpContext.Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
string targetRealm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(spContext.SPHostUrl);
var responseToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, targetWeb.Authority, targetRealm);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(spContext.SPHostUrl + "_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items("+ spUser.Id + ")"); // spUser.Id from spContext
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + spContext.UserAccessTokenForSPHost);

WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (dataStream == null)
{
    ViewBag.res = "nothing";
}else
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var resData = Json(result);
    ViewBag.res= resData.Data; // res must be parse when using js
}
return View();
```

...not sure if it's the best practice but it did the job.